# Newline between variables in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to print two variables at the top of a text file.
I have variables:

```
file=someFile.txt
var1=DONKEY
var2=KONG
sed -i "1s/^/$var1$var2/" $file
```

The output of the last line is: `DONKEYKONG`
While i need it to be:

`DONKEY
 KONG`

I tried:

`sed -i "1s/^/$var1\n$var2/" $file`

`sed -i "1s/^/$var1/\n$var2/" $file`

`sed -i "1s/^/$var1/g $file`

`sed -i "2s/^/$var2/g $file`

However, none of those worked.

EDIT: 
I tried `$var1\\n$var2`, opened the file in notepad and it didn't look right. I opened in notepad++ & sublime and it was the right formatting

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Put a literal newline in the replacement string. You also need to escape it.

```
sed -i "1s/^/$var1\\
$var2/" $file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ed`:

```
printf "%s\n" 1 i "$var1" "$var2" "." w q | ed -s "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1) Include newlines in the command by escaping them with backslashes:

```
sed -i -e "1s/^/${var1}\\
${var2}\\
/" "$file"
```

Make sure `\\` is followed immediately by a newline, no other white space.

Or, 2) avoid the newline escaping issue and take advantage of sed's ability to insert newlines around its hold space:

```
sed -i -e "1h;1s/.*/${var2}/;1G;1h;1s/.*/${var1}/;1G" "$file"
```

To explain this second approach, the commands do the following:

```
h: copy the first line to the hold space
s: replace the first line with the contents of var2
G: append the hold space to the pattern space with a newline separator

After this we've inserted var2 above line 1, on its own line.
Repeat h, s, and G with var1.
Apply all commands to line 1, no other lines.
```